# Will refreshing the Eureka Server monitoring page result in the removal of unavailable microservices?

Tags: java, spring, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I am learning microservice technology based on the latest version of Spring Cloud, When I tried to test Eureka's self-protection mechanism, I found that no matter how to set the properties **lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds** and **lease-expiration-duration-in-seconds**, when I refresh the page, the microservice instances will be quickly cleared, why is this? Will refreshing the Eureka Server monitoring page result in the removal of unavailable microservices??

This is my **client** Configuration file
[image]

This is my **server** Configuration file
[image]

This is the gif I recorded while **testing**
[image]

Comment: refreshing the page doesn't matter

Comment: So...What is the reason for that?@spencergibb

Comment: Likely that app is doing this and you happen to be seeing it in the page. The UI is read only

Comment: Maybe... But, why didn't the properties I configured work? @spencergibb

Comment: I can't say without more information from you.